# Adding html file in magento cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, html

I am really new to magento,I am trying to add my own html page that I have created using visual studio,
its an html file so I have renamed it to .phmtl
I have places my file in this location

```
app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/profile.phtml
```

and then I have placed this code

`{{block type="core/template" template="page/profile.phtml"}}`

in the content area on the cms page.
Once I have done this work nothing happens and page does not use the file profile.phtml
I wanted to know is it possible to add my page this way or am I doing something/everything wrong? 
Also the actual profile.html page is not in php its in simple html/css/javascript/jquery  file with jquery library tags etc in it. 
Please reply if anybody know the answer to my question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are  u seeing in this page?? I mean, Can u see anything after adding?

Comment: no nothing appears

Comment: Can u see what u have added?  {{block type="core/template" template="page/profile.phtml"}} This one coming?

Comment: In the custom lay out I have used modern and empty so page is empty with nothing  on it

Comment: u cleard cache?

Comment: no this block is also not appearing i added in p tags like this  <p>{{block type="core/template" template="page/profile.phtml"}}</p> so only p tags appeared  like this <p></p> on the page

Comment: no i didnt cleared the cache

Comment: Please clear the cache.. nd let me know

Comment: Looks about right. Did you check the HTML source code in your browser? There is probably something wrong with the HTML file. Note that it should not be a full HTML file, because it will be inserted within `<body>`, even with the `empty` layout.

Comment: In cache storage management I had disabled all files before starting do I need to flush them all? @Sundar

Comment: html file is working in my browser as well as on the internet with out magento

Comment: Do i need to remove body tags?? my html file could work that way??@fschmengler

Comment: Do you have a link to the page you are using this?

Comment: Are you using the default/modern template? What is the content of the profile.phtml?

Comment: modren template I am using with empty in columns

Comment: the exact location of this app folder I have used magento1.9/apps/magento/htdocs/app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/profile.phtml

Comment: these are the contents of my html page I have  copied the required parts here http://www.colddays.somee.com/ @Thomas

Comment: Try creating a different block app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/test.phtml

And in that test.phtml file just write this:

<?php
echo "Test";
?>

Comment: ok thanks..I should use notepad for creating this test.phtml?

Comment: Yes thats fine just try and create this and then add the block
{{block type="core/template" template="page/test.phtml"}} and see if it works

Comment: note pad was saving it as .txt so when I changed it to all files then saved it as test.phtml now its giving output test on screen :)

Comment: should I write whole page in php so that It could read..??

Comment: its done thanks @Thomas really helpful you are bless u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the code was correct but these would be the steps to check if something is wrong with the .phtml content

Try creating a different block

`app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/test.phtml`

And in that test.phtml file just write this:

```
<?php echo "Test"; ?>
```

Yes thats fine just try and create this and then add the block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/test.phtml"}}
```

and see if it works, if yes you know your .phtml file is broken so you should debug this then.